# Hostname A Record Not Being Found

Tags: dns, ip-address, hostname, reverse-dns, a-records

I just ran a test on mail-tester.com and it mentioned "We didn't find a server (A Record) behind your hostname host.***.com.".

But my hostname clearly has an A Record that includes its IP address.  Any attempt to add an A Record in WHM through "Add an A Entry for Your Hostname" confirms that "a DNS entry for host.***.com already exists."

**Has anyone run into this problem before?**

*(I also noticed that my reverse DNS is not matching.  The hostname host.***.com is only showing for sent mail, whereas the rDNS shows the IP is associated with a domain that looks like it belongs to the hosting provider that provided us with the IP.  Not sure if this would have any bearing on the hostname's A Record not being recognized.)*

Thanks!

Comment: What does dig return when you run forward and reverse DNS on that host?

Comment: Tell us the hostname to check it. Also check if the name servers of the domain are pointed to the `WHM` name server/s. As for the `PTR` you can speak with the hosting provider to change it. It must be pointed to the mail server's name, the one in the `HELO` of the server.

Comment: I fixed the rDNS problem.  My hosting provider changed the PTR to match the HELO.

But the issue with the A Record not being found still remains.

Dig tells me: id 23529
opcode QUERY
rcode NXDOMAIN
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
"My IP" IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
. 86377 IN SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018021901 1800 900 604800 86400
;ADDITIONAL

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in our zone structure.

Our main domain was pointed to Godaddy when I started setting up our server.  I created our nameservers and host all as separate zone files.  And then when I finally pointed our main domain to our server I set it up on its own zone file.  This was a problem.

The solution was to restructure everything under the domain's zone file.  So the NS and host records are now just records in the main domain's zone file rather than them each having their own zone file.